# Excel Vlookup function not working to show me the discrepancies between 2 sheets

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have two sheets of data with the same three column names. I would like to run a `VLOOKUP()` to tell me which rows are out of equal on the job title.

The data is this:

Sheet1:

| Last Name | First Name | Job Title |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Adam | Katie | CHILD CARE WORKER |
| Adu-Men | Louise | NURSE-RN |
| Akelum | Abimtuja | CHILD CARE SUPERVISOR |

Sheet2:

| Last Name | First Name | Job Title |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Adam | Katie | CHILD CARE WORKER |
| Adu-Men | Louise | Nurse LPN |
| Akelum | Abimtuja | CHILD CARE SUPERVISOR |

in this example the formula should indicate on Abu-Men that there is a job title mismatch. I have created a `VLOOKUP()` but it is only return `#NA`. Can you see what is wrong with my `VLOOKUP()` please.

```
=IF(C2<>VLOOKUP(A2,Sheet2!A:E,3,FALSE), "Job Title Mismatch", "")
```

I tried using a `VLOOKUP()` without success.

```
=IF(C2<>VLOOKUP(A2,Sheet2!A:E,3,FALSE), "Job Title Mismatch", "")
```

Comment: Try `=IF(INDEX(Sheet2!C$2:C$4,MATCH(1,(A2=Sheet2!A$2:A$4)*(B2=Sheet2!B$2:B$4),0))=C2,"","Job Title Mismatch")`.

Comment: The given formula works on my end. What error do you get? also it will be simpler using `XLOOKUP()` --> `=IF(XLOOKUP(A2&"|"&B2,Sheet2!A2:A4&"|"&Sheet2!B2:B4,Sheet2!C2:C4)<>C2:C4,"Job Titile Mismatch","")`

Comment: where do you put this formula?

Comment: Where is your formula entered in which sheet? The above formulas goes to the same sheet as well like yours

Comment: It worth to try to TRIM every value sg. like this: `=IF(TRIM(C2)<>VLOOKUP(TRIM(A2),TRIM(Sheet2!A:E),3,FALSE), "Job Title Mismatch", "")`

Comment: I entered in sheet 1 column d which is blank, there is only data in columns ab and c.

Comment: Same here as well.